# Arch Linux MySQL HTTP Plugin missing?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to revive an undocumented python server at work and I'm running into an issue with a missing file. When attempting to connect to the SQL DB with the credentials I've provided, I run into the following error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/user/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/user/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/user/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Projects/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, 'Plugin http could not be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')
```

Sure enough, there is no `http.so` file at that location, though there is a healthy bunch of others. I cannot find any documentation on why this may be or where I'm supposed to get it.

I'm using Arch Linux, and just installed from the AUR using `sudo pacman -S mysql`. This is just an alias for mariadb from what I can tell, but I don't think that's an issue.

Is this shared object something I can get somewhere? Not sure really what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Came across a thread for HeidiSQL, which from what I read is a MySQL admin tool of sorts. Anyways, a user had the same issue over there, and someone responded with this:

> Just don't use any protocol prefix in the hostname, unless you know it's required and correct. In most cases there must be just the hostname or an ip address, without a protocol.

https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=27104#p34471

Sure enough, I was using `http://` in my hostname. Removing that works just fine, though isn't so much of a solution as a workaround.